# lubuntu 18.04 lts restarts after suspended

Tags: lubuntu, 18.04, lts

I upgraded to lubuntu 18.04 lts lately. I did it from an upgrade option and not from a fresh installation. Everything works great, until I close the lid of my laptop. Lubuntu hangs for a moment and then restarts. The problem does not always appear. It only happens after I've been using the laptop (opening and closing) through out the day.

Under the options of Power management, I have it set to:

When laptop lid is closed: suspend (for both, on battery and unplugged)

Any suggestions?

Thankx!

Comment: What does it show in your Xfce Power Manager settings? (Found under Preferences/Power Manager)  On the first screen there are settings controlling what happens when the lid is closed when on battery or plugged in.  Please edit your question and add this information.

Comment: Hi Marble, the problem doesn't happen every time I close the the laptop lid. It only happens after I've been opening and closing it for a while throughout the day. The laptop does suspend and come back to normal activity "most" of the times after opening and closing the lid. Thanks for answering